# can a quartic graph have 2 turning points?

Tags: polynomials, quartics

Is it possible for a quartic equation when graphed to have 2 turning points and 1 point of inflection. If so what is an example of such equation? I am asking this because i have seen many quartic equations that have 3 or 1 turning point but never seen a quartic graph with 2 turning points.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean there.

Comment: What do you mean with turning points? Local extrema?

Comment: Yes turning point meaning local extrema.

Comment: Any polynomial of even degree must have an odd number of local extrema, because local extrema are precisely the points at which the gradient changes sign.

Comment: So it would not be possible for a quartic equation to have 2 local extrema? as quartic is of even degree, right?

Comment: @SonJerm Correct (assuming you mean just 2).

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the behavior of a polynomial $p(x)$ at $\pm\infty$ by looking at the term of highest degree, because for large $|x|$ the polynomial
$$p(x)=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +c_0$$
is very close, in a relative sense, to $c_nx^n$.

This means that if $n$ is even we must have that the sign as $x\to\infty$ is the same as $x\to -\infty$ because this is true of $c_nx^n$. This can only happen if there are an odd number of turning points. Similarly, for odd $n$ the sign as $x\to\infty$ is the opposite of the sign as $x\to -\infty$, so there must be an even number of turning points.

Comment: I have a question here. For a quartic function, setting the first order derivative equal to zero should give us the local extrema. Since the first derivative is a cubic function, which can have three real roots, shouldn't the number of turning points for quartic be 1 or 2 or 3? Similarly, the maximum number of turning points in a cubic function should be 2 (coming from solving the quadratic).

Comment: Is it because the solution to the cubic will give *potential* extrema (including inflection points)--so even if the cubic has two roots, one point will be a turning point and another will be the inflection point?

Comment: @pgupta A cubic can't have exactly two real roots. Complex roots come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: If the cubic is $(x-3)(x+1)^2$ doesn't it have two real roots, 3 and -1, where -1 has a multiplicity of 2?

Comment: @Pgupta Yes, you're right. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: Thanks, but it begs the question again: if a cubic can have 2 real roots, why can't a quartic have two extrema?

Comment: @PGupta you're right; it's because any root of even multiplicity will not correspond to an extremum.